# How can I pass multiple arguments and execute shell script with echo?

Tags: linux, shell, echo

I want to execute an interactive shell script which asks for multiple user inputs with 'echo' command. The script executes like this:

```
./install.sh
are you sure you want to install (y/n) *<required user input>*
enter root password: *<required user input>*

Installation Successful.
```

I want to execute install.sh in one line command without any further prompt. For this, I tried 'echo' but seems it is not working:

`echo password | echo y | ./install.sh`

How can I execute this script in one shot with all the input values (either using echo or anything else)?

Comment: Prepending the command with `sudo` should get rid of the need to enter the root password. Note that `sudo` has to be placed right before of the `./install.sh` command, not before the `echo` command. For example, `echo y | sudo ./install.sh`

Answer (score 0):

`echo password | echo y | ./install.sh`

You're close, however `echo` does not fit well in the middle of a pipeline: it doesn't do anything with its stdin so you'll lose anything from earlier in the pipeline.

You want to [group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) the `echo` statements and pipe *that* into the install script:

```bash
{
  echo y
  echo "$password"
} | ./install.sh
```

Or, use a `printf` command (the format string is used repeatedly until all the arguments are consumed)

```
printf '%s\n' "y" "$password" | ./install.sh
```